# Populate list dynamically in Codename one

Tags: java, android, codenameone

I had some issues with a List concept in Codename one. I need a list of items populate dynamically at run time, but I don't know how doing it, so anyone helps me regarding this issue?

Comment: Can you give a bit more information about what you want to do and what you exactly mean by "populating dynamically"? What are your sources you get the information for the list from etc.?

Comment: Whenever I write some string in the TextField and then click on the submit button the string will be added to the list.

Comment: A Form isn't updating itself. You have to "form.revalidate()" to do this. Depending on where you add the string. This works when you directly add that string to the component of the form.

Comment: Also check out this post which includes some sample code of list alternatives https://www.codenameone.com/blog/avoiding-lists.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how your list is constructed... E.g. when you have a form with a container, which includes your list as labels.

```
Container c = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
//adding strings as labels
c.add("String1").add("String2");
```

Then you can later on add a String to this container

```
c.add("new String");
```

But the form won't update itself. So you'd have to

`form.revalidate()` OR `form.animateLayout(150)`

to be able to show the changes on the screen.

Comment: Can you please explain why we use .revalidate() or .animateLayout() methods?

Comment: Please, check the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/animations.html) . I get all my information from there and from the [java documentation](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Form.html)